# SQL Server SELECT with Count, Group By, Where and Join

Tags: sql-server-2008, null, count, group-by, where-clause

I previously created this SELECT command in SQL Server, that needs to count how many Employees each Department contains.
This is what I used:

```
SELECT Departments.Description AS [Department], COUNT(Employees.ID) AS [Employees]
FROM Employees 
RIGHT JOIN Departments ON
Employees.DepartmentID = Departments.ID 
GROUP BY Departments.Description
```

And it works fine (also shows the Department, even if there are no Employees).

Now, I want to count only the *currently working* employees, by the following filter:

```
WHERE Employees.JobEndDate = null
```

And I tried doing this:

```
SELECT   Departments.Description AS [Department], COUNT(Employees.ID) AS [Employees] 
FROM Employees 
RIGHT JOIN Departments ON
Employees.DepartmentID = Departments.ID 
WHERE Employees.JobEndDate = NULL 
GROUP BY Departments.Description
```

But now I get no results.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks :)
Mitsy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing if a field returned value is `NULL` is not performed through equal `=` sign but with `IS` operator

```
= null
```

doesn't work, instead write:

```
Employees.JobEndDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Departments.Description AS [Department], COUNT(Employees.ID) AS [Employees] FROM Employees RIGHT JOIN Departments ON Employees.DepartmentID = Departments.ID WHERE Employees.JobEndDate = IS NULL GROUP BY Departments.Description
```